# The Big O on the Dijkstra Fibonacci-heap solution

Tags: algorithm, big-o, dijkstra

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm): `O(|E| + |V| log|V|)`

From [Big O Cheat List](http://bigocheatsheet.com/): `O((|V| + |E|) log |V|)`

I consider there is a difference between `E + V log V` and `(E+V) log V`, isn't there?

Because, if Wikipedia's one is correct, shouldn't it be shown as `O(|V| log |V|)` only then (Removing `|E|`) for a reason I do not understand?)?

What is the Big O of Dijkstra with Fibonacci-Heap?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The complexity of Dijkstra's shortest path algorithm is:

```
    O(|E| |decrease-key(Q)| + |V| |extract-min(Q)|)
```

where `Q` is the min-priority queue ordering vertices by their current distance estimate.

For both a Fibonacci heap and a binary heap, the complexity of the extract-min operation on this queue is `O(log |V|)`. This explains the common `|V| log |V|` part in the sum. For a queue implemented with an unsorted array, the extract-min operation would have a complexity of `O(|V|)` (the whole queue has to be traversed) and this part of the sum would be `O(|V|^2)`.

In the remaining part of the sum (the one with the edge factor |E|), the `O(1)` v.s. `O(log |V|)` difference comes precisely from using respectively a Fibonacci heap as opposed to a binary heap. The decrease key operation which may happen for every edge has exactly this complexity. So the remaining part of the sum eventually has complexity `O(|E|)` for a Fibonacci heap and `O(|E| log |V|)` for a binary heap.
For a queue implemented with an unsorted array, the decrease-key operation would have a constant-time complexity (the queue directly stores the keys indexed by the vertices) and this part of the sum would thus be `O(|E|)`, which is also `O(|V|^2)`.

To summarize:

- Fibonacci heap: `O(|E| + |V| log |V|)`
- binary heap: `O((|E| + |V|) log |V|)`
- unsorted array: `O(|V|^2)`

Since, in the general case `|E| = O(|V|^2)`, these can't be simplified further without making further assumptions on the kind of graphs dealt with.

Comment: Ok, I think I have understood it. Just to make things clear for me: Because (talking about the `decrease-key(Q)`) Fibonacci-heap is `O(1)` then we have `O(E + V log V)` and binary-heap is `O(log V)` so we have `O((E+V) log V) = O(E log V + V log V)`.

If that is correct, can't I say that Fibonacci-heap is just `O(V log V)` as `E` is actually `O(1)`?

Comment: @Nikola |E| is not O(1). In general |E| = O(|V|^2), so you just can't simplify `O(E + V log V)` to `O(V log V)` (unless you make some additional assumptions on the kind of graphs you're dealing with).

Comment: But didn't you say exactly that? `In the remaining part of the sum, the O(1) v.s. O(log(|V|)) difference`? On the Dijkstra unsorted array the `O(E + V^2)` is simplified to `O(V^2)`, isn't `E` the same case here?

Comment: @Nikola Sorry this wasn't clear: a single `|decrease-key(Q)|` operation is `O(1)` with a Fibonacci heap and `O(log(|V|))` with a binary heap. Total there are `O(|E|)` decrease-key operations. With an unsorted array, `decrease-key(Q)` is `O(1)`, but there are still `O(|E|)` decrease-key operations. Still with an unsorted array, `extract-min(Q)` is `O(|V|)`. Hence the `O(|E| + |V|^2)` complexity for Dijkstra's algorithm with an unsorted array. However, as I wrote previously, `|E|` is `O(|V|^2)`, so this can be simplified further to just `O(|V|^2)`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanations! If it is no problem for you, can you also explain to me (or give me a source, because I haven't been able to find where to read on that) about the "In general `|E| = O(|V|^2)`" I cannot explain it to myself at the moment. Also, for the unsorted array, when it is `O(|E| + |V|^2)` and `|E|` is also `|V|^2` it gets `O(2|V|^2|)`, but because we don't care for the constants, that is why we remove it? And last question - if `|E| = O(|V|^2)` shouldn't we write that instead of `|E|`?

Comment: @Nikola Why `|E| = O(|V|^2)`? How many edges in the worst-case can you have in a graph with `|V|` vertices? Just link each vertex to every other vertex. So each of the |V| vertex is linked to |V| - 1 other vertices and you don't want to count twice the edges so in this worst case scenarion |E| = |V| (|V| - 1) / 2 = O(|V|^2).

Comment: @Nikola Yes, O(2|V|^2) = O(|V|^2). Constants are usually discarded since they don't impact the asymptotic complexity.

Comment: @Nikola Why not always write `O(|V|^2)` instead of `O(|E|)`? You may want to know which parts of your formula depend on the number of edges if you're not dealing with worst-case graphs. It makes sense to replace `O(|E|)` with `O(|V|^2)` when another term in the complexity is hiding this substitution (has similar or higher complexity than `O(|V|^2)`): for instance, in the complexity for the unsorted array case.

Comment: Now it is as clear as it could be. Thank you very much for your time, I really appreciate those explanations and they (will) helped me a lot.

Comment: Returning to the topic: `|E|` I understood to be the total edges of the graph. In the worst case I see it it `|E|=O(|V|^2)`. However, what about rectangular grids? It is usually said that Dijkstra is `O=(|V| log|V|) for these grids and therefore I assume that `|E|` can be "deleted", but why?

Comment: @JaviV For rectangular grids `|E|=O(|V|)` (for instance, a N x M grid with |V| = N M vertices has |E| = N (M - 1) + M (N - 1) = O(N M) = O(|V|) edges). Consequently on such a grid, Dijkstra with a Fibonacci heap is `O(|V| + |V| log |V|) = O(|V| log |V|)` and Dijkstra with a binary heap is `O((|V| + |V|) log |V|) = O(|V| log |V|)`. In both cases, `|E|` "disappears" (either being dominated by another term or because it does not add anything).

Comment: Wow exactly the answer I was looking for. Thank you so much! I was missing the |E| = N (M - 1) + M (N - 1) formula, I was not able to get it. By the way, is that formula for 8-connectivity of 4-connectivity?

Answer (score 0):

Dijkstra's is O(|E| + |V| log|V|) with Fibonacci heap and O((|V| + |E|) log |V|) without it.

Both correct in some way. Big O Cheat List showing the most common implementation and Wiki the best there is.

O(|E| + |V| log|V|) isn't in O(|V| log|V|) btw. E is in O(|V|^2), not O(|V| log|V|).